# is there any way to fetch each and every id of every element in a web page

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display(id) { 
      $("html *").attr('id')
      var sub=id.substring(0,1);

      if(sub) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";

      } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch"? Where do you want to put all the ids, into an array or something? What effect are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id]'), function(el){console.log(el.id)});` run say after the load event, will show the id of every element that has one.

Comment: Why u don't use toggle or hide/show functions?

Comment: i want to display single table along with its child table in a web page at a time.say i have a parent table "CATEGORY" and child tables as "ELECTRONICS" , "HOME", "KIDS","BOOKS".futher inside electronics i have "MOBILE","LAPTOP" and so on. now i want when i move my cursor over "ELECTRONICS" then only electronics table should be display similarly when i move my cursor further over "LAPTOP" then "LAPTOP" table along with "ELECTRONICS" table should only be visible nothing else

Comment: <% try  {
getConnection cn=new getConnection();
Connection conn = cn.returnConnection();
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet  rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Category");
%>
 <table style="cursor: pointer" border=4 align="center">

<% ;while(rs.next()){ %>

    <td onmouseover="display(&#39;<%=rs.getString("CID")%>&#39;);return false;"  style="cursor: pointer;">
          <%=rs.getString("CNAME")%>
   </td> 
        
<%} %>
</table> 
<%} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); }%>

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, select elements that has attribute `id` and iterate it using `each` method. Example:

```
$('[id]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function check(id)
    {   
        var s = id.substring(0,1);
        var tableCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
        cellCount = tableCells.length,i;
        for (i = 0; i < cellCount; i += 1) {
                var sub = tableCells.substring(0,1);
                if(strcmp(s,sub))  {
                             document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
}
else  {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";

}
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

function check(id)
{
    var sub=id.substring(0,1);

```
var tableCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
cellCount = tableCells.length,i;
for (i = 0; i < cellCount; i += 1) {
     var sub1=tableCells[i].id;
     var sub2=sub1.substring(0,1);
      if(sub==sub2)  {
                  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";  }
      else   {
                  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";  }
      }
```

}